# Is there any console available to view UGC on ASRP?

Tags: aem

We are implementing communities site using AEM 6.2 and hosting UGC content onto [ASRP](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/communities/srp/asrp.html).
I am able to validate that this works coz the test connection is pass and UGC content is getting loaded onto my communities pages with a path like

Now is there any console or backdoor available OTB to view ugc on cloud; other than creating components, pages and viewing them from front end. Reason are:

1. I am doing migration using the [UGC Migration tool](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-communities-ugc-migration). How to validate migration was successfully complete 100%?
2. If I want to administer the cloud UGC content directly say when site is down for maintenance, how todo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I found a useful tool in GitHub catering my purpose: [SRP Browser](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-communities-srp-browser)
This is bringing all UGC content of a page in a little gui screen they provided + has a json representation of the ugc content as well.

Comment: Good find. I haven't used that tool yet so update your answer once you have explored it's features. Does it allow modifications?

Comment: It is available in github.. I had to modify the pom.xml to point plugin repository to adobe public repo inorder to make it build from local. But otherwise we can simply use as it is.

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash is this tool allows to modification to blog posts ? if yes how ?

Comment: Hi @Rajkumar Samala this is browser view tool only. If you want to modify posts, you can add blog post component, and edit the comments from UI itself.

Comment: Got it, i was looking for whether can we update the blog post property value from back end, so we don't need to author too many blog posts on UI. is that possible to update the Blog post property values from back end in ASRP ?